# Chemical equilibrium constant problem

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium

> In a equilibrium reaction $\ce{CO {(g)} + H2O {(g)} <=> CO2 {(g)} + H2 {(g)}}$, initial concentrations of $\ce{CO}$ and H<sub>2</sub>O are equal and are 0.3 mol/dm<sup>3</sup>. What is
>   the equilibrium constant of the reaction if the equilibrium
>   concentrations of CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub> are equal and are 0.1 mol/dm<sup>3</sup>?

I tried to solve it this way:

$$\begin{split}
\ce{K_r} & = \ce{\frac{[CO2][H2]}{[CO][H2O]} \\
& = \frac{(0.1)(0.1)}{(0.3)(0.3)} \\
& = \frac{(0.1)^2}{(0.3)^2} \\
& = \frac{0.01}{0.09} \\
& \approx 0.11 mol/dm^3}
\end{split}$$

But the correct answer is 0.25 mol/dm<sup>3</sup>

What did I do wrong? What is the right way of solving problems like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.1 is the *equilibrium* concentration of $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{H2}$. 0.3 is the *initial* concentration of $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. Let's plug 0.1 into an ICE-box as $x$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Initial}:& 0.3 & 0.3 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
 & \ce{CO} & \ce{H2O} & \ce{CO2} & \ce{H2}\\ \hline
\text{Change}: & -x & -x & +x & +x \\ \hline
\text{Equilibrium}: & 0.3-0.1 & 0.3-0.1 & 0+0.1 & 0+0.1\\ \hline
\end{array}

*Mass action expression:*

$$K_\mathrm{c} = \frac{(0+0.1)^2}{(0.3-0.1)^2} = 0.25$$